# Typeof operator in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm not expert in typescript and I'm doing some example for testing Http Module with angular 2+.
While debugging, I've noted in this piece of  code : 
 that when I'm clicking the red button, the function `removePost(post: Post){...}` is called and passing an Object of type 'Post' in the function which in turn calling a service to delete the following row in the sand-box.

```
removePost(post: Post) {
    if (confirm('are You sure?')) {
      this.postService.removePost(post.id).subscribe(() => {
        this.posts.forEach((cur, index) => {
          if (post.id === cur.id) {
            this.posts.splice(index, 1);

          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

[Image test debuging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNalZ.jpg)

My doubts starts when I'm trying to do a test debugging with chrome. the Post parameter (would be an object) that arriving in the service literally is converted directly in a number type :

```
removePost(post:Post|number):Observable<Post>{

  const id=typeof post ==='number' ? post: post.id;
  const url=`${this.postsUrl}/${id}`;
  return  this.http.delete<Post>(url,httpOptions);
}
```

I think that probably I didn't understand how the operator typeof works. I mean in this piece of code  `const id=typeof post ==='number' ? post: post.id;`
`typeof` would be a number and so will be set `post` instead `post.id` but the problem is that `post` is an **object**...so how does know typescript has to convert a object in a number? This thing make me very confused....

Comment: Post is object or number/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If post is an object, post.id will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. The reason may be because you are passing the **post.id** to the **removePost()** method.

In this case you are giving the right use to the **typeof** operator, although it is not necessary to be used in this case, since you are explicitly passing a number and not a post object. So your code should work as well like this:

```
removePost(postId:number):Observable<Post>{
  const url=`${this.postsUrl}/${postId}`;
  return  this.http.delete<Post>(url,httpOptions);
}
```

Please, notice I renamed the parameter from post to postId.

In your screenshot I noticed also that for the **updatePost()** you are passing the post object. As a recommendation I would say that you should be consistent in the selection you make. Either go by passing the id to the methods that only require the id or pass the post object (only if you need to access more properties from the post object) in all the methods that follow this pattern. This in reality will not affect functionality, but it will improve the style of the code.

Answer (score 1):

here you call your method

```
this.postService.removePost(post.id)
```

so the `post` is `number` not object.

Comment: Is true...i didn't note that..Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript will perform no runtime conversions. Your code states that `post` is `number | Post` so `removePost` either takes a `number` or a `Post`. So either of these calls would be valid:

```
let p: Post = { } // a radom post from wherever
postService.removePost(p) // argument is Post and that is fine
postService.removePost(p.id) // argument is a number, that is fine too.
```

The role of `typeof` is to find out in which of the two cases we are. If `typeof post ==='number'`  is true we are in the second case, so `post` is a `number`, if it false we are in the first case and `post` is a `Post` object and we can access the `id` property to get the id.

Also interesting to note is that `id` will be typed as `number`. This is due to a feature called type guards (see [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html) and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)) where a union in narrowed by a check such as `typeof post ==='number'`

```
const id=typeof post ==='number' ? post /* post is number here */: /*post is Post here */post.id; // id is number
```